# Turbolinks and 3d party plugins issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have website
http://www.optimapo.ru/
and I have some 3d party scripts installed: 
live chat (https://www.jivochat.com/) and yandex analitics.
But because of turbolinks they don't work properly.
For example live chat appears only on main page. But when we go to another page which is loaded using turbolinks it dissapears.

I include scripts in my code before closing body tag

```
<!-- BEGIN JIVOSITE CODE {literal} -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(){ var widget_id = '2qq06akKwZ';var d=document;var w=window;function l(){
var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/'+widget_id; var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);}if(d.readyState=='complete'){l();}else{if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();</script>
<!-- {/literal} END JIVOSITE CODE -->
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter --> <script type="text/javascript"> (function (d, w, c) { (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() { try { w.yaCounter39034390 = new Ya.Metrika({ id:39034390, clickmap:true, trackLinks:true, accurateTrackBounce:true, webvisor:true, trackHash:true, ut:"noindex" }); } catch(e) { } }); var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], s = d.createElement("script"), f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); }; s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true; s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js"; if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") { d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false); } else { f(); } })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks"); </script> <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/39034390?ut=noindex" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript> <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->

</body>
```

So what do I do to make scripts work with turbolinks?

Comment: have you tried to require your 3rd party scripts in application.js before turbolinks line ?

Comment: @aldrien.h do you mean, that I should just put this code: `(function(){ var widget_id = '2qq06akKwZ';var d=document;var w=window;function l(){
var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/'+widget_id; var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);}if(d.readyState=='complete'){l();}else{if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
` before turbolinks line?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this is strictly possible with how the snippet you include is implemented. Let's look at it, I put it over multiple lines to make it easier to read, but this is all in there:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/'+widget_id;
var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);
```

If you look at turbolinks compatibility, one of the issues it reports are self loading scripts appending to head: http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/

I don't know where `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]` lives on your page, but there's  good chance it's in the head, since it's the first script on the page. Can you change to snippet to insert at the end of the body instead?

Comment: It seems to be the most logical solution, I haven't  tried it yet, but  I will try it in a few days as soon as I will not be as busy as now. It makes sense anyway, so I will give bounty to you and try to do it later.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find a solution that actually works in Turbolinks 5. I've added this piece of code `s.setAttribute('data-turbolinks-track', 'reload');` in between existing code, like this:

```
s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.setAttribute('data-turbolinks-track', 'reload'); s.async = true;
```

Side note: I've also submitted a PR with this solution to [Turbolinks Compatability](https://github.com/reed/turbolinks-compatibility/pull/80) repository

Answer (score 1):

Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process and sometimes scripts needs refresh. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events) is the rails guide for using tubolinks on page load. It is coffescript. Here is javascript equivalent :

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: does not help!!

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet works for me.

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  ...your code ...
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: does not help too

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this gem in your application:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Follow the set-up instructions [here](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).
Place your Metrika and JivoSite scripts onto the bottom of the page. You do not need to require them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, just change

```
jivo_id = 'ID-MY-ACCOUNT';
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/Brunomm/5c227e6c254332290812

```js
jQuery(document).on('page:load', runChat);
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {runChat();});

// Chat online jivo
function runChat(){
 $('#jivo-iframe-container, .jivo_shadow, [src*="//code.jivosite"]').remove();

 delete(window.jivo_api);
 delete(window.jivo_config);
 window.jivo_magic_var = undefined;

 window.$jivosite = null;
 (function(d,s){
  var z = $jivosite=function(c){ z._.push(c) },
      el_script = z.s = d.createElement(s),
      e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      jivo_id = 'ID-MY-ACCOUNT';

  z.set=function(o){
   z.set._.push(o)
  };
  
  z._=[];
  z.set._=[];
  $.async = !0;
  el_script.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
  
  el_script.src='//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/'+jivo_id;
  z.t=+new Date;
  el_script.type="text/javascript";
  e.parentNode.insertBefore(el_script,e)
 })(document,"script");
}
```